# How to post list of list using Ajax to Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

now i try to send data from template which is list of list datatype by using ajax, and this is my code.

template (JS)

```
var mydata = [['tom', 18, 'new york'], ['jack', 16, 'london']];

var data = new FormData();
mydata.forEach(function (value, index) {
       data.append('staff[]',value );
});

$.ajax({
   url: "/myfunction",
   type: "POST", 
   data:data,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
})
.done(function(data){
            
});
```

routes.py

```
@app.route('/myfunction', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def myfunction():
    staff_list = request.form.getlist('staff[]')
    print(staff_list)
```

And i should get list of list data the same as `mydata` in template but i get string inside list instead, and this is the output of `staff_list` variable.

```
['tom,18,new york', 'jack,16,london']
```

So are there any way to get list of list variable like this.

```
[['tom', 18, 'new york'], ['jack', 16, 'london']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you the following sample code for such uses:

html

```
<a type="submit" onclick="sampleDelete({{ elem.id }})" class="btn btn-cstm"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

js : You don't have to use swal. This is just an example.

```
function sampleDelete(elem_id) {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are your sure ?',
        text: "text-kjgnknt.",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#46ad7a',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        cancelButtonText: 'No',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/path/path/func_name',
                data: 'elem_id=' + elem_id,
                success: function (msg) {
                location.reload();
                }
            });

        }
    })
}
```

py

```
@app.route("path/path/func_name", methods=["GET","POST"])
@roles_required('member', 'seller')
def func_name():
    elem_id = request.form.get('elem_id')
    ...
    return create_json_response({'message': 'lkfnbkjerlnn.'}, True, 200), 200
```